# Cherokee installation on ubuntu

Tags: server, configure

Actually i want to install **cherokee** web server on my *Ubuntu* 15.10 **desktop**. When i downloaded the source file and then tried to configure it like
 `configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc` 
but it's not working and it shows a error that file not found.Actual error is `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`
 I have already installed the softwares like lib , make etc....

---

I am stuck in that please help me............

---

Answer (score 0):

To build from the repository, you will require autoconf, automake, and libtool tools to be available, typically available on your distribution either by default or by running the following on Debian-based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool
```

You should run `./autogen.sh` to set up the environment and generate `./configure`

After running `./configure`, issues the `make` command, and then `sudo make install`

```
cd cherokee
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```